# Windows workstaiton virtual NIC for softphone voice vlan

Tags: vlan, softphone

We are going to be installing softphones on our Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 10 workstations. I have read that it could be possible to setup virtual NICs in the machines and have them connect to a voice vlan that has QoS setup on it. I have tried using the Widnows loopback adapter as the virtual NIC, but I'm not sure if that's the proper way to handle this. I know this get's more into the Cisco side of things, but once I do get a proper virtual NIC, does anyone know how to configure the switches to provide a voice vlan to that NIC through the same physical connection? We have a CCM phone system, and an I3 phone system. The I3 phone system is what will use the softphones. We have Cisco IP phones for the CCM PBX that can connect to a voice vlan and supply a data vlan to a machine connected through the phone on the same physical conneciton. Will this same kind of configuration work for the virtual NIC on the Windows workstations. Any info on any of this to get me pointing in the right direction would be very helpful. The most important part right now is to setup a proper virtual NIC, or at least to know if it's possible with my current NIC driver. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I had to do was download 0001-DiagnosticAllin1(2.0.2.11)(www.station-drivers.com).zip for Windows 10. This is specific to the kind of network adaptor I have which is RealTek. I heard for Intel NICs you can download something called ANS. With this software you have the ability to setup VLANS which will give you the virtual NIC. And the same configuration that we use for our Cisco phones to get a voice vlan also works for the virtual adaptor.